# Share folders for different network cards

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, network-share

I have a server WS2008R2 with 2 network cards (Both are on the same LAN)
Eg:

> **server1**
>
> IP1: 192.168.0.2
>
> IP2: 192.168.0.3

I'd like to share some directories on IP1, and other directories on IP2. 
For example:

> \192.168.0.2\dir1
>
> \192.168.0.3\dir2

And if possible put an alias to such IP, for example:

\alias1\dir1

\alias2\dir2

This is possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I think you're falling into an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trap. What is that larger issue that you're trying to resolve by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/09/03/using-the-multiple-nics-of-your-file-server-running-windows-server-2008-and-2008-r2.aspx has a detailed list of possible network configurations for a fileserver.

You would be looking at section 2.3 - Standalone File Server, 2 NICs on server, single subnet.

For **really** basic load balancing ([with a bunch of limitations and downsides](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175767)), you don't really need to do anything - the server will register all it's IP addresses in DNS, and clients will pick one essentially at random.  You can't control which clients connect to which interfaces, but they will balance out somewhat.

A better plan, assuming you are doing this to get more speed or fault tolerance is to setup teaming, also covered in that blog post.  With teaming, windows treats both network cards as a single interface, with double the speed.  On Server 2008, this requires manufacturer specific drivers and software.  Server 2012 has this feature baked in.  There are different kinds of teaming - which works best for you will depend on the NICs and the switch they connect to.

Comment: Actually what I need is not load balancing, but "Emulate" two different servers eg:

\\ server1 \ folder1

\\ server2 \ folder2

Comment: @romanracca ok.  But you still haven't explained *why*.  What is the overall goal here?  Please edit that into your question so we can offer better advice.  The more detailed you are about your goals the better we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I see some potential solutions to your problem - although as others have prompted about why you want to do this, my solutions may not be applicable.

1 - Using shares may not be the solution, rather FTP folders (this way you can control IP/folder flow.

2 - If your users are coming from a network for which you know the subnet(s) of, you could have routing definitions on your router/switch to route some traffic to one address and some to another (think of NAT, but local.) - and you could build on this by perhaps having a port forwarding set up like this: 192.168.5.5:1234 -> 192.168.5.6 and not define a port (no-translation).

3 - Port Forwarding - this could potentially work if you could set up your folders with an FTP or HTTP-like presentation and bind their delivery to a local port.

...Just winging ideas, there may be a better solution than shares is all I'm trying to say.